# Are the statement and proof of this theorem regarding the linear transformation of a contented set satisfactory? CH Edwards, Theorem IV 5.1

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

My questions are about Theorem IV 5.2 of https://www.scribd.com/read/282634061/Advanced-Calculus-of-Several-Variables

> If $\lambda:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a linear mapping, and $\mathcal{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is contented, then $\lambda\left(\mathcal{B}\right)$ is contented,  and
> $$\mathit{v}\left(\lambda\left(\mathcal{B}\right)\right)=\left|det\lambda\right|\mathit{v}\left(\mathcal{B}\right).$$

My first question regards the possibility of a negative volume.  I understand that in the physical world there is no such thing.  But **why should a mathematician rule this out?**  In particular, **why should we simply coerce the transformation using an absolute value?**

The next question regards his assertion:

> If $\left|det\lambda\right|\neq{0},$ then a standard theorem of linear algebra states that the matrix $A$ of $\lambda$ can be written as a product
> $$A_{1}A_{2}\dots{A_{k}}$$
> where each $A_{i}$ is either of the form [every diagonal element but one equal to 1]

> [image]

> or of the form [a single off-diagonal element]

> [image]

According to Nering's **Linear Algebra and Matrix Theory,** there are three types of elementary row operations on matrices:

- I. Multiply a row by a non-zero scalar
- II. Add one row to another
- III. Interchange two rows

There are three analogous elementary column operation.

The associated elementary matrices are, for example example:

$$I.\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

$$II.\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$III.\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Nering gives:

> Theorem II-6.1 Any non-singular matrix can written as a product of elementary matrices.

Note, in particular, Edwards omits all mention of the third type of operation (which requires two off-diagonal elements.)  The type which would toggle the sign of the determinant.  Certainly, if the composite transformation has a positive determinant, there will be an even number of elementary swaps.  But **simply omitting the third type of elementary operation seems unjustified.  Is it?**

And, finally, Edwards states, for the case of $\lambda_{i}$ being of type II:

> Since we have seen that $\lambda_{i}$ preserves the volumes of intervals, we then have
> $$\underset{j=1}{\overset{p}{\cup}}\lambda_{i}\left(I_{j}\right)\subset\lambda_{i}\left(\mathcal{B}\right)\subset\underset{j=1}{\overset{q}{\cup}}\lambda_{i}\left(J_{j}\right)$$
> and
> $$\underset{j=1}{\overset{p}{\sum}}\mathit{v}\left(\lambda_{i}\left(I_{j}\right)\right)>\mathit{v}\left(\mathcal{B}\right)-\varepsilon,
> \underset{j=1}{\overset{q}{\sum}}\mathit{v}\left(\lambda_{i}\left(J_{j}\right)\right)<\mathit{v}\left(\mathcal{B}\right)+\varepsilon.$$

(The $I_{j}$ and $J_{j}$ are enclosed and enclosing intervals used to define a contended set. See below.)

Though I believe these conditions to hold, **I don't see how the first follows from the fact that the volume is unchanged by an elementary skew transformation. Does it?**

This final point is important to me because it seems to apply to continuum mechanics, where in an ideal continuum, adjacent parcels remain adjacent.  The proof may be trivial, but it seems worth stating for completeness.

So, in summary, I ask: **are my critiques of Edwards's statement and proof of this theorem are warranted?**

From Edwards, IV 2.

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: What is a "contented set"?

Comment: Short answer: A contented set is a set for which volume is defined.  Long answer, see the botom of my edited question..